# How can I read a csv file and pass the values to a List<String> in flutter?

Tags: csv, flutter, dart

Well, I'm new at flutter doesn't know how to read a csv file, my csv file has a string per line,
All I want is read from csv file to a `List<String>` then pass to my Simpleautocompletetext widget suggestions

```
SimpleAutoCompleteTextField(
              key: key,
              suggestions: o,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Name',
                hintText: 'Input Name',
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                isDense: true,
              ),
            ),
```

I am follow this
https://github.com/felixlucien/flutter-autocomplete-textfield/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart
He has a list on the same file, but i want to import from my csv. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

load csv from assets and split with new Line

```
class CsvImp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CsvImp createState() => _CsvImp();
}

class _CsvImp extends State<CsvImp> {

  List<String> added = [];
  String currentText = "";
  List<String> csv = new List();
  GlobalKey<AutoCompleteTextFieldState<String>> key = new GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    loadCSV();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("csv"),
        ),
        body: csv.length == 0 ? new Container() :
        new SimpleAutoCompleteTextField(
          key: key,
          suggestions: csv,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Name',
            hintText: 'Input Name',
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            isDense: true,
          ),
        ),

      );
  }

  Future<String> loadAsset(String path) async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString(path);
  }

  void loadCSV() {
    loadAsset('assets/file.csv').then((String output) {

      setState(() {
        csv = output.split("\n");
      });

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Where the function loadCSV() initiate?

Answer (score 3):

the best solution is Package [CSV](https://pub.dev/packages/csv). Based on this package, i made a simple GitHub Repository for reading data from csv file and converting it to list and using in a ListView Builder (see [this](https://github.com/hosseinvejdani/flutter-csv-file-read)). you can use README.md on that repository and enjoy :)).
the sample code is here:

```
  List<List<dynamic>> data;

  @override
  void initState() {
     loadAsset();
    super.initState();
  }

  loadAsset() async {
    var myData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/data/category.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);
    setState(() {
      data = csvTable;
    });
  }
```