# How to import bulk data in firebase firestore database from excel or google spreadsheet or CSV using flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have flutter app where User fill a long form. but I want to add another button where when user want click and upload 'excel or spreadsheet or CSV' having same data as form and this data store in firebase firestore.
please help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: what you can do is read the csv file, row by row, insert it into your model and write it to firestore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no API for doing that, Firestore doesn't have an option in which you can upload an Excel or a CSV file and convert the data automatically to Firestore. To solve this, you should write some code for that. As also Krish Bhanushali suggested in his comment, you need to [read the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61086280/how-can-i-read-a-csv-file-and-pass-the-values-to-a-liststring-in-flutter), line by line, save that data into an object of a custom class, and then write all the data to Firestore. This means that each line you read will be added in Firestore as a document.

Comment: I have used grahamearley package to import to Firestore, and it works pretty cool. https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript, https://levelup.gitconnected.com/import-data-from-google-sheets-to-firestore-using-google-apps-script-b6f857f82a2 - I just wish it supported Batched writes. If you can really restrict your user from importing anything weird, it may help. Otherwise build your importer as suggested above as the way to go for production.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefoo. connect to the db, import your csv, done.

Its trialware but it works flawlessly